# Clipped Text & Shadows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, typography

I'm trying to get the text in this example to display properly, but I keeps clipping text & shadows in various letters and I can't figure out why and how to fix it.

Here's a jsfiddle (Removed), so you can understand it fully.   <strike>Please refresh the jsfiddle once it loads, as the first letter clipping doesn't appear like it does on a regular published page.</strike>

The problem is <strike>on load (after you refresh) the 'F' & it's shadow will be clipped.</strike>  Then, mouseover the text - 'Second' will appear, then mouseout and first word will appear again, but then 't' shadow is clipped.

Can't figure out how to fix these.  Could someone please help me clear these clipping bugs.
Thanks,  Bill

**UPDATE:**  I figured out the 'F' letter clipping problem (updated jsfiddle) - I will need help w/ the 't' clipping - Thanks, Bill

BUMP - Someone? Pretty Please - Bill

Comment: It looks like you're splitting the text and animating each letter individually?  Just trying to get a grasp of how your JS works.

Comment: Yes, using Lettering plugin to split up each letter and then using hoverwords plugin along with jQuery Easing to do the animation.  At the end of js you can see the majority of my hacks.  I'm new to stackoverflow, so I'm not sure what you'll need - just ask if you need more info - I'm desperate for some quality help - thanks  Bill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem has to do with the way fonts are rendered. Certain fonts (like the one you're embedding) have serifs which extend beyond the "box" of the letter itself. In typical typography, this is handled by allowing the render area to extend beyond the box itself - because most applications don't make a box around each letter.

I think the issue you're having stems from the fact that each letter is actually a `<span>`, which means that it does, in fact, have a box. Your JS is then messing with `opacity`, `overflow` and positioning, which causes the CSS rendering to box off each individual `<span>` as it is being rendered.

My suggestion would be to avoid using the explicit widths / overflows that you're applying to the spans, and instead let them auto-size, and control absolute positioning.

If each span has the same z-index, and they are spaced correctly, this should give you what you're looking for, without causing clipping.

UPDATE:

The issue is that the font renders in a fashion which overlaps letters (as many script-style fonts do). As a result, you -must- render this font in such a way that it extends beyond the bounds of it's box.

However, when CSS from the plugin turns the individual letters partially transparent, transparent items can't extend beyond the outsides of their boxes... so the clipping occurs.

The solution is to increase the size of the box sufficiently that the clipping doesn't occur, and allow the boxes to overlap.

In other words, the trick is to provide `padding-right` and `padding-left` which give the font letters enough space to fully express, then adjust with negative `margin-left`, to move the letters back together.

For this font, at this size, the style which makes it work is:

```
.lslide_wrap a span span.sl-w1 {
    ...
    /* Add the following 2 lines: */
    padding: 0 100px 0 22px;
    margin-left: -22px;
}
```

An updated version of the original jsFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/8XFSx/16/).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  The plugin uses animate, which creates overflow-hidden during rendering.  (Jsfiddle updated) I stripped out the overflow callouts on the letter elements and assigned width:auto, z-index is same for each letter in a word but it's still clipping a little bit.  I even removed the width assignments in plugin.  Appreciate any code help to squash this clipping bug. Thanks - Bill

Comment: Turns out the thing causing you the grief is the opacity toggle. When `span.sl-w1` items get turned partially opaque, that is too complicated a rendering mechanism for Chrome to figure out - so it just clips, rather than letting the partially transparent items continue to show.

The trick is to give each letter enough padding that it can fully express. I've updated your jsFiddle to reflect. http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/8XFSx/16/

Comment: Can you explain what the pad-rt of 110 is for?  I tried changing it's value, but it didn't seem to make any rendering difference.  The first letter's shadow is now clipped on mouseout - go figure - I tried all day to come up w/ a fix.  Can you show me how to fix it - I'm stumped. (New [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/billparti/8XFSx/)- Thanks, Bill

Comment: Yes - the reason it's there is to provide enough space around the letter to allow the extremely large letters (like the capital F - which extends about 95 px beyond it's own span) plus the shadows (which extend another 10 or so px) to have enough space to render. If you drop the value, you'll start to see shadow clipping. The `padding-left` is to provide the same thing on the left, and the `margin` negative value is to un-do the offset which the `padding-left` creates. :) The shadow works fine for me in your new fiddle, using Chrome. Any chance you could mark this as the answer?

Comment: btw - your fiddle has significant problems in IE9. No shadows, and the opacity doesn't change, because IE requires it's own proprietary CSS.

Comment: If you look at padding right, I set to 0px - no change in rendering - can you please test.  The others I understand.  In chrome-mac, I see clipping of 'F' shadow Same problem in Safari, Opera is even worse, Firefox seems ok. IE shadows is next task - I have solution for that, but need to get clipping bug squashed ;-) https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15268289/chrome_mac.png

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to test in a Mac environment. However, based on your screenshot, I'm guessing that you actually need to increase the size of the box, not decrease it. And - I would not drop the `padding-right` - it's there for a reason. On Windows machines, without that, you get nasty clipping during the animation. Everything renders fine once the letters are stopped - but while moving, they look terrible unless that padding is there. Welcome to the joys of embedded fonts. :\

Comment: Also - your latest round of changes have made the `SECOND` word render with the `S`, `E`, and `C` overlapping in a weird way. Not sure what you changed.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, see above.

Comment: Bill, I think you're over-thinking this, my friend. Don't do the crazy jQuery fiddling in order to override the sizes over and over again... Use the solution I gave you - and if it gets overwritten by the plug-in, just use `!important` - as in `padding: 0 120px 0 50px!important;`

Comment: As usual, I try to do it the difficult way ;-) Thanks for getting me back on track.  It's working now. Thank you so much.  Got to tackle IE shadows now, hopefully I'll be able to reasonably approximate shadows.

Comment: Before you go, I'm trying to hide the initial animation, what do I need to change:  $('.sl-wrapper').promise().done(function() {
    $('.lslide_wrap').css({'margin-top': '0px'}).show();      
  });  Thanks

Comment: That I'm not as sure about - I don't usually do too much with animation sequences. However, `.show()` will just toggle from `display: none;` to `display: block;` as an inline style - and your animation scheme is toggling `opacity` - so you might want to change it to set the `opacity` css to `1` instead of changing `margin` and calling `.show()`